# does $\oint_C P\,dx + Q \,dy = 0$ for all curves imply $P$ and $Q$ are harmonic conjugate functions?

Tags: complex-analysis

> (a) Suppose $P(x,y)$ and $Q(x,y)$ are conjugate harmonic functions and $C$ is any simple closed curve, prove that $\displaystyle \oint_C P\,dx + Q \,dy = 0$.
> (b) If for all simple closed curves $C$ in the region $R$ , $\displaystyle \oint_C P\,dx + Q \,dy = 0$, is it true that $P$ and $Q$ are harmonic conjugate functions? i.e. is converse of (a) true?

For (a) since they are harmonic conjugate functions so they should satisfy Cauchy-Riemann equations and using Green's theorem, it can be shown. The problem is asked under the topic [Morera's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem). Can it be shown using Morera's theorem? How is it related to Morera's theorem?

For (b), the closed loop integral for all curves implies $\displaystyle \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$. How show that it is harmonic or non harmonic?

EDIT:: There seems to be a problem which states that if $\displaystyle \oint_C Pdx + Q dy = 0$ for all curves in the region bound by $C$ then show $\displaystyle \oint_C Q\,dx - P \,dy = 0$. I can't prove this either but I think they are equivalent.

Help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(a) When $P$ and $Q$ are conjugate real harmonic functions of $(x,y)$ on a simply connected domain $\Omega\subset{\mathbb C}$ then $f:=P+iQ$ is an analytic function of $z:=x+iy$ on $\Omega$, by definition of "conjugate harmonic". Therefore by Cauchy's theorem for any closed curve $\gamma$ in $\Omega$ one has
$$0=\int_\gamma f(z)\ dz=\int_\gamma (P+iQ)\ (dx+i dy)=\int_\gamma (Pdx-Qdy) + i\int_\gamma (Qdx +P dy)\ .$$
It follows that $\int_\gamma (Pdx-Qdy) =0$ for all $\gamma\subset\Omega$. Note the essential hypothesis that $\Omega$ is simply connected. Consider the example
$$P(x,y)={y\over x^2+y^2},\quad Q(x,y)={x\over x^2+y^2}\qquad\bigl((x,y)\ne(0,0)\bigr)\ .$$
Then
$$P+iQ={ix+y\over x^2+y^2}={i\over z}=:f(z)$$
is analytic on $\Omega:=\dot{\mathbb C}$, but for $\gamma$ the unit circle on has
$$\int_\gamma (Pdx-Q dy)={\rm Re}\left(\int_\gamma {i\over z}\ dz\right)=-2\pi\ne0\ .$$
(b) When $\int_\gamma (Pdx+Qdy)=0$ resp. $\int_\gamma (Pdx-Qdy)=0$ for all closed $\gamma\subset\Omega$ this only implies that $(P,Q)=\nabla f$, resp. $(P,-Q)=\nabla f$ for some scalar function  $f:\ \Omega\to{\mathbb R}$, but neither $f$ nor its derivatives have to be harmonic.

Comment: could you help me with one part? why is $f(z) = P + i Q$ analytic function?

Comment: @Mula Ko Saag: See my edit.

Comment: i asked a [similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358606/showing-that-there-exists-analytic-function-for-oint-c-pdx-q-dy-0-for-any) could you check it, if you have time. 
And thank you very much for your time :))